# Finding the first three terms of the Laurent series near $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, contour-integration, laurent-series

> Let $$f(z) = \frac{1-e^z}{\sin^2z}$$
>   Find the first three terms of the Laurent series near $z=0$ and then evaluate $$I =\oint_{|z| = 1}f(z)dz$$

If we write $\sin^2 z = \frac{1-\cos2z}{2}$ and then try to use Taylor expansions of $e^z$ and $\cos z$, we should then divide two power series and this is really difficult by hand(this question was in an exam). Also if we do this, what's the radius of convergence? Is there any easier method for finding the first three terms of the Laurent series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}6+\ldots\,,\;\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}6+\frac{z^5}{120}-\ldots\implies$$

$$\implies\sin^2z=z^2-\frac13z^4+\frac{2z^4}{45}\ldots\implies$$

$$\frac1{\sin^2z}=\frac1{z^2\left(1-\frac13z^2+\ldots\right)}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}3+\frac{z^4}9+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\frac{1-e^z}{\sin^2z}=\left(-z-\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}6-\ldots\right)\frac1{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}3+\frac{z^4}{49}\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{z^2}\left(-z-\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}3+\ldots\right)=-\frac1z-\frac12-\frac z2+\ldots$$

Comment: *Happy New Year !*, my friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the radius of convergence for this series? Also why you factored $z^2$ in the denominator? Was it necessary?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Bonne Anné, mon cher ami !

Comment: @S.H.W We got a Laurent series depending only on the development in the third line, which is a geometric series one valid for $\;\left|\frac{z^2}3\right|<1\iff |z|^2<3\iff |z|<\sqrt3\;$ . And yes: I needed to fact our that $\;z^2\;$ in the denominator to develop the resulting geometric series.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think we should have $|\frac13z^2+\ldots|<1$ for convergence not only $|\frac{z^2}3|<1$.

Comment: @S.H.W  For $\;z\;$ close to $\;0\;$ that is the case since the series in the denominator in the second term in the third line is a convergent series...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry but I couldn't follow your reasoning. Could you explain more, please?